# IE Angular webapplication automation in powershell

Tags: angularjs, angular, internet-explorer, automation, powershell-4.0

I would like to know is there any support provided by PowerShell to automate the application developed in AngularJs. I am looking for support similar to IE Automation using PowerShell where I inspect elements and pass the necessary inputs, perform actions like submit,navigation between pages etc.,

When I tried passing the inputs for the inspected fields and the values are reflecting in the respective textbox fields, its getting failed while submitting the form.

Any suggestion on this is highly helpful and saves a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

Browser understand the HTML. We can write PowerShell script to automate IE.

You can use example below.

In which you can try to pass the URL of your angular application. Then you can try to insert values and click buttons.

```html
$ie = New-Object -ComObject 'internetExplorer.Application'
$ie.Visible= $true # Make it visible

$username="abcde"

$password="12345"

$ie.Navigate("Enter your URL here....")

While ($ie.Busy -eq $true) {Start-Sleep -Seconds 3;}

$usernamefield = $ie.document.getElementByID('txt_username')
$usernamefield.value = "$username"

$passwordfield = $ie.document.getElementByID('txt_password')
$passwordfield.value = "$password"

$Link = $ie.document.getElementByID('submit')
$Link.click()

#$ie.Quit()
```

If this is not your requirement then try to post your sample code and provide a detailed information about that.

We will try to provide further suggestions.